Git clone permission denied on Mac
So i am trying to clone a repository but then i encountered an error, i believe i have installed necessary things but then i need help
This is the code i ran  git clone git@gitlab.com:techibytesmedia/script-jobs.git
This is the error i got

Cloning into 'script-jobs'...
git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

I am expecting a successful clone because i also ran sudo  git clone git@gitlab.com:techibytesmedia/script-jobs.git

What happens when you clone a different repository? In any case, this has nothing to do with PHP, don't blindly apply tags!

You need to be authenticated if it is no public repository. Make sure your public SSH key (of your terminal client) is registered in Github/Gitlab Settings. Alternatively you may try the https URL for your repo.

sudo is pointless here, because this is an issue about your permissions on the Github servers, it's unrelated to your local permissions. Generally speaking: never use sudo with git or any other source code manipulation workfolw. It's way more likely to make things worse than better.

I'm guessing you need to upload your publick key to gitlab. You can find your public key here: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub. If you don't find it there, you can generate one by running: ssh-keygen -b 4096 -t rsa (don't enter passphrase when prompted for one). Now, google how to set your account with your public key to navigate your way to the settings, and you should be all set.

Moreover creating a checkout with sudo will wreck permissions so you will not be able to work with the files you checked out.
